# how to onboard parachain to Kusama after auction

Tags: parachain, auctions, lease

I am following this tutorial to get a slot on the Kusama https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/acquire-a-testnet-slot/. The process of generating `WebAssembly runtime` file and `parachain genesis state` file is clear. it is also clear how to participate in auction. Could you please let me know what are the steps after the auction is won and lease has started? is running a `collator node` the only thing needed or are there other actions needed to be taken, maybe using the account that registered ParaId?

what are the steps to do if the parachain is not onboarded? I see that at https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fkusama-rpc.polkadot.io#/parachains there are parachains in gray although their slot lease has started. Why are they not onboarded how to avoid their issues? Thank you!